# I can't get a POST to work with my ASP.NET Web API 2 server

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am using Web API 2. I have the following in my controller (and more):

```
   [Route("about")]
    public string GetAbout()
    {
        IPrincipal principal = RequestContext.Principal;
        IPrincipal user = User;
        return string.Format("principal: {0}, user: {1}", principal == null || principal.Identity == null ? null : principal.Identity.Name, 
            user == null ? null : user.Identity.Name);
    }
    [Route("license/exchange")]
    //public string PostUser([FromBody]string value)
    public XmlDocument PostLicenseExchange(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        Trap.trap();
        int x = 3;
        return xml;
    }
```

In my browser, If I put in the URI `http://localhost:13770/about`, I get the data back.

But I I try a POST to `http://localhost:13770/license/exchange`, I get:

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at EnforcedVacationCommon.LicenseServer.ServerComm.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) in c:\src\EnforcedVacation\EnforcedVacationCommon\LicenseServer\ServerComm.cs:line 137
  InnerException:
```

I am calling using:

```
Start() {
                // start the request
                Uri httpSite = new Uri(URI_LICENSE_SERVER);
                WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(httpSite);
                wreq.Method = "POST";
                wreq.ContentType = "text/xml";

                RequestState requestState = new RequestState(asyncCallback, xmlDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting), msgGuid, wreq);
                wreq.BeginGetRequestStream(GetRequestStreamCallback, requestState);
}
        private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            RequestState requestState = (RequestState)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                using (Stream postStream = requestState.Request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult))
                {
                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestState.XmlRequest);
                    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    postStream.Close();
                }
                requestState.Request.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, requestState);

        }

        private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            RequestState requestState = (RequestState)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
// exception on this call
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) requestState.Request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify that this is a Http Post method with an attribute on the action result as such.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("license/exchange")]
    //public string PostUser([FromBody]string value)
    public XmlDocument PostLicenseExchange(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        Trap.trap();
        int x = 3;
        return xml;
    }
```

You can see the documentation by [clicking here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#add-routes).

Comment: I don't think it is needed as the document says - "By default, Web API looks for a case-insensitive match with the start of the controller method name." So PostLicenseExchage should match HttpPost.

Comment: Unfortunately adding that didn't help.